# Separating Variables Inside an Array

Tags: php, mysql

Hey i have an array an I need to separate each value so it would be something like this

```
$arry = array(a,b,c,d,e,f)
$point1 = (SELECT distance FROM Table WHERE Origin = a AND Destination = b);
$point2 = (SELECT distance FROM Table WHERE Origin = b AND Destination = c);
$point3 = (SELECT distance FROM Table WHERE Origin = c AND Destination = d);
$point4 = (SELECT distance FROM Table WHERE Origin = d AND Destination = e);
$point5 = (SELECT distance FROM Table WHERE Origin = e AND Destination = f);
$point6 = (SELECT distance FROM Table WHERE Origin = f AND Destination = g);
$point7 = (SELECT distance FROM Table WHERE Origin = g AND Destination = f);

$total_trav = $point1+$point2+$point3+$point4+$point5+$point6+$point7
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is the array is random, above i just arrange it in a sequential sometimes the array would be (a,v,d,z,l,m) --> i need to sequence that to a->v, v->d, d->z ect. thats my problem

Comment: You're still not being clear by what you mean by random......how is it random, and how does it need to be organized to work in your query??? You need to be alittle more clear as to what you need if you want help, I would suggest adding to your question WHAT YOU ACTUALLY NEED, regardless of randomness, what you typed in your comment to my answer, showed me that even though the letters you chose were random, the order was still the same

Comment: Let me know if what I did helps you at all, or if Im completely misunderstanding what you need....

Comment: thankx what i need is just the to order that random letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could all be done in SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(distance) 
FROM table 
WHERE (origin='a' AND destination='b') 
   OR (origin='b' AND destination='c')
   OR (origin='c' AND destination='d')
```

and so forth.

Comment: yes but exactly but how would i extract the a->b, b->c, c->d its from array from another function sometimes the array(a,r,s,t,b)

Answer (score 2):

Simple just use list();

```
list($point1,$point2,$point3,$point4,$point5) = $arry;
```

Then do your query like so....

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(distance) FROM table WHERE (origin='$point1' AND destination='$point2') OR (origin='$point2' AND destination='$point3') OR (origin='$point3' AND destination='$point4') OR (origin='$point4' AND destination='$point5')
```

**EDIT**

Ok based on what you need below in the comments,  I worked up a simple solution for you....

```
$arr = array("Vegas","Iowa","Utah","Washington"); //your array

//First part of query string build... 
$sql = "SELECT SUM(distance) FROM table WHERE";

//Loop through the array...based on its # of contents
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
   if(!empty($arr[$i+1])){
   $sql.=" (origin='".$arr[$i]."' AND destination='".$arr[$i+1]."') OR";}
 }
  //Hack off the end bit, which contains an OR appended to the string...
  $sql = substr($sql, 0, -3);

  //$sql is now ready to be used in a query
  mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: but the array is random, above i just arrange it in a sequential sometimes the array would be (a,v,d,z,l,m) --> i need to sequence that to a->v, v->d, d->z ect. thats my problem

Comment: so whats the problem.....with list you have access to the variables, in your example a->v v->d, d->z is the exact same as point1->point2  point2->point3  point3->point4, beside you didnt ask that in your question, you never even mentioned that

Comment: im sorry i am new in this forum i encounter error while posting :-( I didnt finish my question when i click post i thought im having problem with my connection

Comment: my question is the value of array is random i just need to sequence that.

Comment: I know, you already said that, but thats a very broad question.....ie what context does 'random' mean, for this particular problem....and how do you want to sequence it??  Ie what kind of data are you working with?

Comment: Do you mean that the amount of entries in the array will sometimes be 4, and sometimes be 16. So you have no control over the amount of variables you'll end up with

Comment: im working with dijkstra's Algorithm I have a DB with all possible routes the dijkstra's Algorithm will calculate the shortest path with a given origin and destination example Chicago to California the place you will pass (CA, LA, Vegas, utah, denver, nev, iowa, chicago). i need to sum the distance from CA-LA, LA-Vegas. then total. all the sum.

Comment: that still doesn't tell me if the distances are random or in order.....what is it?  When you say random, do you mean, the amount of distances will be varying? or do you mean, that they will be jumbled, and not in order?  You see.....random can mean many different things.....if they will return in order, but there will just be unkowable amount of distance nodes, then the problem is easy....but if by random, you mean that the nodes will return in a random jumbled fashion....the problem becomes magnitudes harder because how do you tell an origin from a destination etc etc

Comment: no its not the distance that are random is the location that are random i just need to sequence. like (a,b,c,d,e), (b,a,d,c) ect but from point a to b or b to a the distance is the same

Comment: Did my new solution above help? I think it might

Comment: sorry for that I just need to order the letters no matter the array are random

Comment: ????????????????  what do the letters mean, how are you getting the data, youre not being very clear at all....how can you possibly even begin to fathom how to sort random variables, with no 'meaning' attached to them?????

Comment: Regardless though....that snippet I posted above, will get used at some point in your code...  :)

Comment: It workssss!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! THanksssssssssssss ALOOTTTTTTTTTtt

Answer (score 1):

use [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

will extract the elements from the array to variables using the key as the name.

Comment: but the array is random, above i just arrange it in a sequential sometimes the array would be (a,v,d,z,l,m) --> i need to sequence that to a->v, v->d, d->z ect. thats my problem